# What is design pattern/paradigm for ASP.NET web-apps?

Tags: java, design-patterns, web-development, paradigms

I don't actually know if my question is correct, but working on a webapp porting from ASP.NET world to Java + Spring platform I came up with this question in mind.

Using Spring MVC, the new version of the the application, I'm obviously applying MVC pattern, but which was the ASP.NET design/paradigm.

I know that ASP.NET uses event-oriented paradigm, but is this a design pattern? Hope to be clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Asp.Net is really based on a Design Pattern. It's just a Framework developed with a similar concept to the Windows Forms.

If you want to use a pattern to develop a Web Site with .Net Framework, I suggest to have a look to [Asp.Mvc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). It's another technology from Microsoft based on the MVC pattern.

---

At first point, I have partially misunderstood the question. If you are trying to understand the pattern eventually behind Asp.Net to convert it into a MVC pattern, well, there is no pattern as I said before.

Asp.Net it is  totally based on the [postback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4251346/1950995) concept. Basically, every time an event (like a click on a button) is fired, the Asp.Net engine execute a post request to the same page, so it can call the method attached to the event.

So, if you want to convert the old project using an MVC pattern, I think you will spend most of your time converting the events into manual post requests.

Anyway, when you are facing a conversion from a technology to another it's better to understand what happens behind the scenes, instead just converting literally the old code into the new one.